# VS2017 VSIX Installer failed to install

Tags: installation, vsix, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to install the VS2017 VSIX Installer so I can create a setup project for my application.  I've tried to run this package several times without success.

It seems to be failing for the following reason... 
Package 'VSInstallerProjects,version=0.8.4' failed to install. System.IO.IOException: The file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WizardFramework.dll' already exists.

I've even renamed the .WizardFramework.dll but it just created a new one and then failed again.

Any help to resolve this will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

## Here's the entire Log file .....

2017-06-23 11:55:58 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
2017-06-23 11:55:58 AM - -------------------------------------------
2017-06-23 11:55:58 AM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
2017-06-23 11:55:58 AM - 15.0.26403.7 built by: D15SVC
2017-06-23 11:55:58 AM - -------------------------------------------
2017-06-23 11:55:58 AM - Command line parameters:
2017-06-23 11:55:58 AM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\duane\Downloads\InstallerProjects.vsix,/installas:2024,/callingprocessid:21024
2017-06-23 11:55:58 AM - -------------------------------------------
2017-06-23 11:55:58 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
2017-06-23 11:55:58 AM - -------------------------------------------
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - Initializing Install...
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - Extension Details...
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    Identifier         : VSInstallerProjects
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    Name               : Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    Author             : Microsoft
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    Version            : 0.8.4
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    Description        : This official Microsoft extension provides support for Visual Studio Installer Projects in Visual Studio 2017.
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    Locale             : en-US
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    MoreInfoURL        : 
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    InstalledByMSI     : False
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.6.1,)
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - 
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    SignatureState     : ValidSignature
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    Certificate Info   : 
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        -------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=MOPR, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        [Serial Number] : 330000017D015E4C2BE2BCF66900000000017D
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        [Not Before]    : 2017-02-15 2:10:16 PM
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        [Not After]     : 2018-05-09 3:10:16 PM
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        [Thumbprint]    : 69713C6FF47FADFF90C9465F7783E6E08232B28F
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - 
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    Supported Products : 
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -            Version : [15.0]
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - 
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    References         : 
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    Prerequisites      : 
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        -------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        Name         : Visual Studio Min Shell
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        Version      : [15.0.26205,16.0)
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - 
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        -------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        Identifier   : Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        Name         : ClickOnce Publishing
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -        Version      : [15.0,16.0)
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - 
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - Signature Details...
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM -    Extension is signed with a valid signature.
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - 
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - Searching for applicable products...
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated)
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
2017-06-23 11:55:59 AM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2017
2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: Looking for master PkgDef file, Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\master.pkgdef

2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: Creating PkgDefCacheNonVolatile
2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: Double-checking master pkgdef file
2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefManagement initialized
2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: RootFolder, Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\

2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: ShellFolder, Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\

2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefSearchPath, Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.admin.pkgdef

2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: ImageManifestSearchPath, Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Users\duane\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_0ee0412c\Extensions

2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: ApplicationExtensionsFolder, Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions

2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: "ZeroImpact" = dword:0, "MergeRegistry" = dword:3
2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: User extensions enabled by setting, Path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_0ee0412c\ExtensionManager\EnableAdminExtensions

2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefCache flags, PKGDEF: 7001
2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
2017-06-23 11:56:00 AM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefManagement startup complete
2017-06-23 11:56:01 AM - The extension with ID 'VSInstallerProjects' is not installed to Visual Studio Community 2017.
2017-06-23 11:56:07 AM - The following target products have been selected...
2017-06-23 11:56:07 AM -    Visual Studio Community 2017
2017-06-23 11:56:07 AM - 
2017-06-23 11:56:08 AM - Beginning to install extension to Visual Studio Community 2017...
2017-06-23 11:56:08 AM - VSIX TaskScheduler: VSIX Auto Updatetask already exists.
2017-06-23 11:56:12 AM - Package Microsoft.Windows.UniversalCRT.Msu.8 is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.2,6.3)'.
2017-06-23 11:56:12 AM - Package Microsoft.Windows.UniversalCRT.Msu.81 is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.3,6.4)'.
2017-06-23 11:56:12 AM - Package Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1.1,6.4)'.
2017-06-23 11:56:13 AM - Package Microsoft.Windows.UniversalCRT.Msu.7 is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
2017-06-23 11:56:13 AM - Package Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.KB2882822.Win7 is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
2017-06-23 11:56:13 AM - Package WebSocket4NetV2 is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
2017-06-23 11:56:13 AM - Package Microsoft.Net.4.6.1.FullRedist is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1.1,10.0.10241)'.
2017-06-23 11:56:13 AM - Package Microsoft.Windows.81SDK.Store.DirectX.Msi is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.3]'.
2017-06-23 11:56:13 AM - Package Microsoft.Windows.81SDK.Store.DirectX.Msi is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.3]'.
2017-06-23 11:56:13 AM - Package Microsoft.Windows.81SDK.Desktop.DirectX.Msi is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.3]'.
2017-06-23 11:56:13 AM - Package Microsoft.Windows.81SDK.Desktop.DirectX.Msi is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.3]'.
2017-06-23 11:56:13 AM - Windows Installer found the package 'sqllocaldb,version=15.1.61703.130,chip=x64,language=en-US' superseded but corresponding compatible package information was not found. Attempts to repair will be skipped and that to uninstall may leave the cache behind.
2017-06-23 11:56:13 AM - Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.WindowsIdentityFoundation.Msu is not applicable. Skipping it due to the following reason(s): The current OS Version '10.0.15063.0' is not in the supported version range '(,6.2)'.
2017-06-23 11:56:22 AM -

Package 'VSInstallerProjects,version=0.8.4' failed to install. System.IO.IOException: The file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WizardFramework.dll' already exists.

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.VsixInstaller.InstallCore(String localPath, String installDir, InstallablePackage pkg)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.InstallerBase.InstallHelper(InstallData installData)
2017-06-23 11:56:22 AM - Skipping cache of package 'Component.VSInstallerProjects,version=0.8.4' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2017-06-23 11:56:28 AM - Install Error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package 'VSInstallerProjects' failed to install
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. The VSIX installer cannot install 'Microsoft Analysis Services Projects'. The file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Business Intelligence Semantic Model\1.0\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.Core.dll' already exists. MSFT recommends deleting the file as a fix and rerun the installer. However the installer creates the file and then a moment later fails to install because the file already exists....I need to get an installer that works without tripping over itself...

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem.
What did the trick for me was go to the folder:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies**

and rename the following 2 files:

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeployWizard.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.WizardFramework.dll

Also rename the following folder if it exists:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI**

Once done, I could install the extension.

Mind you, I have a Professional version, so in the folder-paths you should probably replace "Professional" with "Community".

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, THANK YOU..... I initially tried it thru VS and it failed twice... needless to say I was a bit discouraged.  Finally I did the renames all over again, but this time I rebooted my computer first.  Then after the reboot I downloaded the VSIX file from Microsoft and clicked on it without launching VS -- finally success!

Comment: @Duane:  Since his answer worked for you, you should marked it as solving your problem -- give it a big green check mark.

Comment: @Duane With what names you have renamed the files, I didn't see any files in the "PublicAssemblies" folder. Could you please help me out

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error message. The error message appeared when trying to install a VS extension to VS 2017 after installing VS 2019 on my machine.

It looked like the VS 2019 install might have distrubed the 2017 VSIX.

SOLUTION: 
I did a repair on the version of 2017 on my machine and that fixed my problem. Just another solution for anyone with this problem. 
To do a repair, open, 'Control Panel | Uninstall a program | right click on Visual Studio 2017'. Either the uninstall or the change (try change option first) will give you the option to 'Repair' the version of 2017 currently on your machine.