# VSIX Installer failed for QT

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm trying to install `Qt Visual Studio Tools` in VS-17 (version 15.7.6) but it gives me the following error message along the log file.

[image]

Log file:

```
7/21/2020 2:37:35 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
7/21/2020 2:37:35 PM - -------------------------------------------
7/21/2020 2:37:35 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
7/21/2020 2:37:35 PM - 15.9.3043
7/21/2020 2:37:35 PM - -------------------------------------------
7/21/2020 2:37:35 PM - Command line parameters:
7/21/2020 2:37:35 PM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Pro,/skuVersion:15.0.27703.2047,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017,/culture:en-US,C:\Users\Nouman\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXgmxjuzy4.vsix
7/21/2020 2:37:35 PM - -------------------------------------------
7/21/2020 2:37:35 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
7/21/2020 2:37:35 PM - -------------------------------------------
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM - Initializing Install...
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM - Extension Details...
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  Identifier         : QtVsTools.13121978-cd02-4fd0-89bd-e36f85abe16a
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  Name               : Qt Visual Studio Tools
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  Author             : The Qt Company Ltd.
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  Version            : 2.5.2.1
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  Description        : The Qt VS Tools for Visual Studio 2017 allow developers to use the standard development environment without having to worry about any Qt-related build steps or tools.
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  Locale             : en-US
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  MoreInfoURL        : http://www.qt.io/
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  InstalledByMSI     : False
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.6,)
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM - 
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  SignatureState     : Unsigned
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  Supported Products : 
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -          Version : [15.0.28010.0,16.0)
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -          Version : [15.0.28010.0,16.0)
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -          Version : [15.0.28010.0,16.0)
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -          Version : [15.0.28010.0,16.0)
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM - 
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  References         : 
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  Prerequisites      : 
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      -------------------------------------------------------
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Name         : Visual Studio core editor
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Version      : [15.0.26208.0,16.0)
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM - 
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      -------------------------------------------------------
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Name         : Visual Studio C++ core features
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Version      : [15.0.26208.0,16.0)
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM - 
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      -------------------------------------------------------
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Name         : VC++ 2017 v141 toolset (x86,x64)
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -      Version      : [15.0.26208.0,16.0)
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM - 
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM - Signature Details...
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM -  Extension is not signed.
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM - 
7/21/2020 2:37:36 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

I had tried various solution posted in this forum like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725879/vs2017-vsix-installer-failed-to-install) one but could able to find the mentioned files/directories which the OP is asking to rename/delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed an old version i.e. [2.1.2 version](https://download.qt.io/development_releases/vsaddin/2.1.2/) it worked. Different versions are available [here](https://download.qt.io/development_releases/vsaddin/).